# How to conditionally create an AWS::Events::Connection resource based on if a secret key is defined or not

Tags: aws-cloudformation, aws-event-bridge

I currently have this cloud formation template that is supposed to create an event bridge resource with all the necessary configurations, but I can't get it to create because I can't get cloud formation to verify if a key exists in the secrets manager or not.

to be more clear, I want my `event-bridge.yml` template resource to only be created if my key `${Stage}/${SubDomain}/django-events-api-key` is already defined in the secrets manager and has a valid value(meaning it does not only have an empty string or a AWS::NoValue); this because I need to create the key after the stack is created and deployed, before the stack is not deployed, so I can't execute my command to generate the key

I have this:

`event-bridge.yml`

```yaml
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: "2010-09-09"
Description: "Event scheduling for sending the email digest"
Parameters:
  SubDomain:
    Description: The part of a website address before your DomainName - e.g. www or img
    Type: String
  DomainName:
    Description: The part of a website address after your SubDomain - e.g. example.com
    Type: String
  Stage:
    Description: Stage name (e.g. dev, test, prod)
    Type: String
  DjangoApiKey:
    Description: Api key for events bridge communication
    Type: String

Conditions:
  DjangoApiKeyExists: !Or [ !Not [ !Equals [ !Ref DjangoApiKey,  !Ref AWS::NoValue ] ], !Not [ !Equals [ !Ref DjangoApiKey,  "" ] ] ]

Outputs:
  DjangoEventsConnection:
    Description: Connection to the Django backend for Event Bridge
    Value: !Ref DjangoEventsConnection

Resources:
  MessageDigestEventsRule:
    Type: AWS::Events::Rule
    Properties:
      Name: !Sub "${SubDomain}-chat-digest"
      Description: "Send out email digests for a chat"
      ScheduleExpression: "rate(15 minutes)"
      State: "ENABLED"
      Targets:
        - Arn: !GetAtt MessageDigestEventsApiDestination.Arn
          HttpParameters:
            HeaderParameters: { }
            QueryStringParameters: { }
          Id: !Sub "${SubDomain}-chat-digest-api-target"
          RoleArn: !GetAtt MessageDigestEventsRole.Arn
      EventBusName: "default"

  DjangoEventsConnection:
    Type: AWS::Events::Connection
    Properties:
      Name: !Sub "${SubDomain}-django"
      AuthorizationType: "API_KEY"
      AuthParameters:
        ApiKeyAuthParameters:
          ApiKeyName: "Authorization"
          ApiKeyValue: !Ref DjangoApiKey
```

in a `main.yml` template I pass the key variable like this:

```
  EventBridge:
    DependsOn: [ VpcStack, DjangoEventBridgeApiKey ]
    Type: AWS::CloudFormation::Stack
    Properties:
      TemplateURL: ./event-bridge.yaml
      Parameters:
        SubDomain: !Ref SubDomain
        DomainName: !Ref DomainName
        Stage: !Ref Stage
        DjangoApiKey: !Sub '{{resolve:secretsmanager:arn:aws:secretsmanager:${AWS::Region}:${AWS::AccountId}:secret:${SubDomain}/django-events-api-key}}' <--
```

but that will always fail because the key is not defined, I would like to pass an empty string or something I can use as a conditional

I have also tried defining the secret, so it exists:

```yaml
Resources:
  DjangoEventBridgeApiKey:
    Type: AWS::SecretsManager::Secret
    Properties:
      Name: !Sub ${Stage}/${SubDomain}/django-events-api-key
      Description: !Sub Credentials for the event bridge integration https://api.${SubDomain}.circular.co
      Tags:
        - Key: Name
          Value: django-events-api-key
  EventBridge:
    DependsOn: [ VpcStack, DjangoEventBridgeApiKey ]
    Type: AWS::CloudFormation::Stack
    Properties:
      TemplateURL: ./event-bridge.yaml
      Parameters:
        SubDomain: !Ref SubDomain
        DomainName: !Ref DomainName
        Stage: !Ref Stage
        DjangoApiKey: !Sub '{{resolve:secretsmanager:${DjangoEventBridgeApiKey}}}'
```

But that for some reason, is still making my condition above fail, making the stack attempt to execute, I still cant figure out why is my condition not working

Any ideas on how to make this better? any help provided will be super useful to me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay found out the biggest problem with my implementation, on `event-bridge.yml`:

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: "2010-09-09"
Description: "Event scheduling for sending the email digest of chat messages"
Parameters:
  SubDomain:
    Description: The part of a website address before your DomainName - e.g. www or img
    Type: String
  DomainName:
    Description: The part of a website address after your SubDomain - e.g. example.com
    Type: String
  Stage:
    Description: Stage name (e.g. dev, test, prod)
    Type: String
  DjangoApiKey:
    Description: Api key for events bridge communication
    Type: String

Conditions:
  DjangoApiKeyExists: !Not [ !Equals [ !Ref DjangoApiKey,  "" ] ] # <-- this works

Outputs:
  DjangoEventsConnection:
    Condition: DjangoApiKeyExists
    Description: Connection to the django backend for Event Bridge
    Value: !Ref DjangoEventsConnection

Resources:
  DjangoEventsConnection:
    Type: AWS::Events::Connection
    Condition: DjangoApiKeyExists
    Properties:
      Name: !Sub "${SubDomain}-django"
      AuthorizationType: "API_KEY"
      AuthParameters:
        ApiKeyAuthParameters:
          ApiKeyName: "Authorization"
          ApiKeyValue: !Ref DjangoApiKey
          # This does not update when we change the secret - so we need to force an update - need a more permanent solution
          # ApiKeyValue: pop

  MessageDigestEventsApiDestination:
    Type: AWS::Events::ApiDestination
    Condition: DjangoApiKeyExists
    DependsOn: DjangoEventsConnection
```

on `main.yml`

```
...
  DjangoEventBridgeApiKey:
    Type: AWS::SecretsManager::Secret
    Properties:
      Name: !Sub ${Stage}/${SubDomain}/django-events-api-key # <- this was missing ${Stage}
      SecretString: " "
      Tags:
        - Key: Name
          Value: django-events-api-key
  EventBridge:
    DependsOn: DjangoEventBridgeApiKey
    Type: AWS::CloudFormation::Stack
    Properties:
      TemplateURL: ./event-bridge.yaml
      Parameters:
        SubDomain: !Ref SubDomain
        DomainName: !Ref DomainName
        Stage: !Ref Stage
        DjangoApiKey: !Sub '{{resolve:secretsmanager:arn:aws:secretsmanager:${AWS::Region}:${AWS::AccountId}:secret:${Stage}/${SubDomain}/django-events-api-key}}'
      Tags:
        - Key: Stage
          Value: !Ref Stage
        - Key: SubDomain
          Value: !Ref SubDomain
        - Key: SecretKeyName
          Value: !Ref DjangoEventBridgeApiKey
```